# Inn characteristic in Aut

Tags: group-theory

If $G$ is a centerless group then is $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$ necessarily characteristic in $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$?

The condition of being centerless is necessary as $D_8$ provides a counterexample otherwise.

Comment: This is only true if $Aut(G)$ is a complete group; that is, $Aut(G)\cong Aut(Aut(G))$.  In particular, $G=S_3\times S_3$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @steve Thank you. I still have to figure out why every outer automorphism of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ should move $\mathrm{Inn}(G)$, but the example $S_3\times S_3$ does work. I wish this was posted as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: @SteveD In fact it is true if and only if ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is complete.

Comment: @SteveD,DerekHolt — I just realised that your comments are relatively young. If you want reputation for your answer, post it, and I'll remove mine.

Comment: @jmc: I don't think think this question is suitable for mathoverflow, so I am not bothered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers from the comments (hence CW):

> This is only true if $\textrm{Aut}(G)$ is a complete group; that is, $\textrm{Aut}(G) \cong \textrm{Aut}(\textrm{Aut}(G))$ via the canonical homorphism $Aut(G)\to Aut(Aut(G))$. In particular, $G=S_{3} \times S_{3}$ is a counterexample. – [Steve D](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1446/steve-d)

> @SteveD In fact it is true if and only if $\textrm{Aut}(G)$ is complete. – [Derek Holt](https://mathoverflow.net/users/35840/derek-holt)

Answer (score 1):

Some more on the question.

If $Aut(G)$ is complete, then $Aut(Aut(G))=Aut(G)$, and then the only automorphisms $Inn(G)$ has to worry about are conjugations; it is thus characteristic.

If $Inn(G)$ is characteristic, then it is normal in $Aut(Aut(G))$.  If there exists $\beta\in Aut(Aut(G))\setminus Aut(G)$, then $\beta$ acts on $Inn(G)$ by conjugation, inducing an automorphism.  Thus there is an $\alpha\in Aut(G)$ such that $\beta^{-1}\alpha$ acts as the identity on $Inn(G)=G$. But then $\beta^{-1}\alpha\beta=\beta$ is in $Aut(G)$, a contradiction.  Thus $Aut(Aut(G))=Aut(G)$.

Finally, to see $G=S_3\times S_3$ is a counterexample, simply note that $Aut(G)=(S_3\times S_3)\rtimes C_2$, where the outer automorphism swaps the two factors. Now there are two copies of $S_3\times S_3$ in $Aut(G)$: the obvious one (the inner automorphisms), and the not-so-obvious one generated by the usual $3$-cycles, and the "transpositions" given by the outer automorphism, and a product of involutions in each $S_3$ factor that commutes with this outer automorphism.  These two copies of $S_3\times S_3$ are permuted by $Aut(Aut(G))$ (this permutation is the outer automorphism of $Aut(G)$).

Comment: $\beta^{-1} \alpha$ may acts non-trivially on $A$. Why does $\beta^{-1} \alpha$ acting trivially on $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ imply $\beta^{-1}\alpha\beta = \beta$ ?